# Callback jquery.scrollview.js

Tags: jquery, scrollview

I'm using the jquery Scrollview plugin (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-scrollview/) to scroll drag a div with overflow hidden.

My question is how I go about to get a callback function on this?

Anyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When are you wanting the callback function to be fired?

The plugin itself already has several events bound, for example:

```
.mouseout(function(){ self.stopgrab() })
.mouseup(function(){ self.stopgrab() })
```

Can you piggy-back on these?

***Edit:***

Try this for the `mouseup`

```
$('.image:eq('+examplevariable+')').scrollview({ 
    grab:"images/openhand.cur", 
    grabbing:"images/closedhand.cur" 
}).mouseup(function(){
    alert("test mouseup");
});
```

The existing mouseup functionality should be preserved, and this tagged onto the end.

Comment: Ok, thanks a bunch.

I would like to fire the callback when the scrolling have ended, so I guess that it would be good to use the .mouseup function. But how can I reach that function from this:

$('.image:eq('+examplevariable+')').scrollview({
    grab:"images/openhand.cur",
    grabbing:"images/closedhand.cur"
});

Comment: James, how do I do that? Can't find it in any preferences and settings.